# how to get 2 different results from the same column using MySQL Query

Tags: php, sql

I want to get 2 results at the same time, from a single column.

For example:

```
    $MySQLQuery = $wpdb->get_results("
       SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
       WHERE 
       meta_key='client_name' AND meta_value = 'Jhon' AND
       meta_key='order_completed' AND meta_value = 'yes'

        ");
```

Edit:
i want to get 2 distinct results from the same column.

The Columns are called "meta_key" and "meta_value"

In the column "meta_key" I want to get the 2 results:

```
client_name
order_completed
```

In column "meta_value", it is the result of columns "meta_key"

```
john
yes
```

Comment: A single column cannot contain `Jhon` and `yes` at the same time

Comment: well, i did. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using

> GROUP BY

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_value IN ('john', 'yes')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

In this way, MySQL returns all the values ​​of the "meta_value" with the condition

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UNION to concatenate 2 queries.

Or try:

```
select * from 
(select * from TABLE WHERE condition = "value"),
(select * from TABLE WHERE condition = "value"),
```

Comment: i want to get 2 distinct results from the same column.

The Columns are called "meta_key" and "meta_value"

In the column "meta_key" I want to get the 2 results:

client_name
order_completed

In column "meta_value", it is the result of columns "meta_key"

john
yes

Comment: If you want unique results try: UNION ALL or SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: I managed to solve it, take a look at my answer in the post. By the way, thank you very much, your answer made me look at some MySQL arguments so I found the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: No Problem. It's nice to see somebody is active searching for solution and post his solution for the community. Also it is just nice to upvote instead of posting a thank you ;-).
But i think "HAVING" maybe gives you the outcome for what you are searching for in this specific case.
But HAVING COUNT * is a condition. So with HAVING COUNT (*) = 2 you get only an outcome, when there are just and only an aggregation of 2. Is that what are you searching for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for hehe